# Go言語で外部プログラムの標準出力・入力を扱う方法について

Tags: git, go

## 実現したいこと

Go言語を用いて、Gitのリベース処理を自動化するコマンドを作りたいです。
細かいコミットが重なったために、リベースでSquashしようとすると以下のようなコマンドを実行して、

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

すると、git-rebase-todoがエディタで立ち上がると思います。しかし、その都度エディタが立ち上がり対象のコミットに対してsquashに書き換えるのが面倒です。そこをコマンドでサクっと修正できるようにしたいと考えています。

## 試したこと

Go言語でまずはvimを起動させて値を取得するというコードを実装してみましたが、上手くいきません。

```
vimCmd := exec.Command("vim", "text.txt")
vimStdout, _ := vimCmd.StdoutPipe()
vimStderr, _ := vimCmd.StderrPipe()
vimCmd.Start()
/* 以下3行は有効にするとvimエディタが起動(例外で落ちる) */
//vimCmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
//vimCmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
//vimCmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
go func() {
    scannerOut := bufio.NewScanner(vimStdout)
    scannerErr := bufio.NewScanner(vimStderr)
    for scannerOut.Scan() {
        for scannerErr.Scan() {
            lineErr := scannerErr.Text()
            fmt.Println("[stdErr] ", lineErr)
        }
        lineOut := scannerOut.Text()
        fmt.Println("[output] ", lineOut)
    }
}()
vimCmd.Wait()
```

実行すると以下のメッセージが出力されます。

```bash
[stdErr]  Vim: 警告: 端末への出力ではありません
[stdErr]  Vim: 警告: 端末からの入力ではありません
```

**実現したいこと** を達成するためにアプローチ自体が間違っていれば、それについてもアドバイスを頂けたらと思います。

Comment: 入出力の話ではないのですが、autosquashオプションを利用してはいけませんか？

Comment: >  keitaro_so さん コメントありがとうございます。autosquashオプションを利用しても問題ありません。

Comment: 作成中のプログラムから Vim を起動（実行）する予定だとすると、目的は `git` コマンドに起動された Vim をコントロールしたいという事のようですので、違う事をしようとしているように見えます。
また、 Vim は端末を制御するプログラムですから、「Go言語で外部プログラムの標準出力・入力を扱う方法」を理解しても、それだけではコントロールできません。
Vim をコントロールする方法はいくつか考えられますが「実現したいこと」からすると、そこで苦労するよりもっと良い方法がありそうです。
例えば、`git` が起動するエディタを `git -c 'core.editor=...` でコントロールしやすいコマンドに変えたり、`git` の実行コマンドを工夫して（エディタが起動する） `-i` の使用を止める、などです。

Comment: @mjy さんありがとうございます。
> 目的は git コマンドに...
はい、例示した例はサンプルですが、実際にはgit rebase -i のインタラクティブで立ち上がるエディタ(vim固定)を操作したいと考えていました。
もう少し調査したいと思います